# Force Furnace Blower to Run on Separate Schedule to Circulate Air

Tags: hvac, thermostat, heating, furnace

Appreciate any and all insights you might provide. I could tamper with this until I figured it out but I'm hoping that your collective expertise will save me some time and keep me safe! I've got an OH3 ThermoPride oil furnace with a blower motor. I'm include photos of the wiring harness on the blower and the wiring schematic. My current thermostat only has R & W wires to turn on the furnace which triggers the blower to run. Cold spots are a real issue especially in bedrooms and I'd love to force the blower to run on a regular schedule that I can control/set with an app. My plan is to have a separate wifi connected thermostat in the utility room that I can control with a scheduling app.

3 Core Questions

- how do I wire that thermostat to the blower terminal strip? Do I just add a piggyback onto the C terminal on the blower where the white wire coming from the red primary thermostat wire (per the schematic)?
- am I correct that it's not a problem if both tstats call for the blower to run at the same time?
- any recommendations of a programmable switch or tstat that I could use to control only the blower?

Thanks so much.

Wiring Schematic

[image: Wiring Schematic]

Blower Wiring Harness

[image]

Here's what the relay looks like. You can barely make out the C (upper screw terminal) and G (lower terminal).

[image]

Comment: If you can find the "Fan Center Relay" the "G" terminal is customary for running fan-only.

Comment: Can you trace that three-wire cable from the blower terminal block back to the fan relay?

Comment: Hey @Ecnerwal and ThreePhaseEel, thanks for your thoughts and prompt responses. I've located the fan center relay, it was pretty obvious once I went back in. As I'm sure you know, it's just a 24v relay and transformer. How would you propose that I wire in either a wireless switch or separate tstat to force the blower to run? Should I create a separate exterior jumper between the G and C 24v terms on the relay and put a switch between them? This is basically the relay that is installed: White-Rodgers-90-113-Fan-Control-Center-120VAC relay

Answer (score 2):

### You should be able to wire a thermostat to R, G, and C on the fan control relay and have it control the fan

According to the wiring diagram on your furnace, the fan relay selects between AUTO operation (where the blower thermostat in the plenum controls the fan) and always-on operation, so you should have no issues wiring your new thermostat to the R, G, and C terminals on the fan relay so that it can "take over" the fan if desired.

Comment: Thank you @ThreePhaseEel, that makes sense to me and is super helpful. If I just wanted it to be a WiFi switch that runs on a schedule, could I just place that switch in-line on a 14 AWG wire between the G and C terminals? I don't actually see a need to have the R wire since I'm not actually needing to have the fan running be controlled by the temperature of the utility room. Am I missing something?

Comment: @JulienGeiser you need to connect the switch between G and R since the fan relay coil is between G and C (think like a simple lightswitch controlling a lightbulb)